# background-repeat: repeat-y; not working

Tags: css

I'm quite new to CSS and for sure I'm missing something basic here but I really can't figure it out. This is the code:

In HTML I have this:

```
<div class="tab-left"></div>
```

In CSS:

```
.tab-left {
    background-image: url(images/left.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    position: absolute;
    width: 96px;
    height: 1049px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    z-index: 99999;
    }
```

However, the repeat-y property does not work. This is the site in question: http://ziontouch.com/wordpress/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your repeat is working fine. The problem is that the `height` isn't tall enough to reach the bottom edge of the page.

Comment: You're right, but isn't there a way to repeat the image in relation to the page height? If the page height will increase by adding new posts how can I set the top-left image to auto repeat itself so that the layout will stay the same?

Comment: Easiest way to do that is using a `table` with nine cells, or use `top: 0px; bottom: 0px;` with appropriate `position` settings.

Answer (score 0):

The background *is* repeating.

The problem is that the `.tab-left` has an explicit `height` set, which isn't as tall as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It *works* but the height of your DIV element is not big enough to fill up the whole space...

Answer (score 0):

It is repeating, just up to 1049px as specified by your height attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a bigger height.

```
.tab-left {
    height: 1622px;
}
```

That reaches exactly the beginning of the border bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using jQuery in your page so what you can do is use jQuery to find the height of your div#page and use that value to set the heights of your tab-left and tab-right classes.

Like this:

`$('div.tab-left').css('height',$('div#page').height());`

`$('div.tab-right').css('height',$('div#page').height());`

Then as content is added to your page, it will adjust as necessary.